# How to set border color using ffmpeg deshake filter

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` using [deshake filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake) with `edge=0` setting produce green color border, how to make it black?

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf deshake=edge=0 video_ffmpeg_deshake.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `deshake` filter by default sets zeroes into the no longer valid edge pixels. In a YUV representation, this looks green. So you have two possiblities:

- Use an RGB representation of the image, so that zeroes look black
- Overlay an image, that consists only of a black border over the result

I recomend the second option, as it is much easier: Create a PNG image, that is transparent with the required black borders, then use the `overlay` filter to put it on top of the video.

Comment: Black borders is not consistent across frames, so for each frame I need separate mask, which looks like not an option.

Comment: If the frame is not consistent, then using a bigger frame to make seems it consistent looks like a brilliant option!